# How to count git commits per user in a date range?

Tags: git

The command `git shortlog -sne` is exactly what I need, but I want to be able to specify a date range for that which isn't an option for `shortlog`. Is there another way to accomplish this same thing, but for a specific date range?

Comment: `git shortlog --since=2013 --before=2014` works for me.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Although `git shortlog --help` doesn't seem to specify it, `shortlog` takes the same `--since`, `--after`, `--before` and `--until` parameters that `git log` does. So, for example:

```
git shortlog -sne --since="01 Jan 2015" --before="01 Feb 2015"
```

Note:
This was verified on git 2.1.0 running on Fedora 21 and on git 1.8.3.1 running on RHEL 7.1. I don't have older systems at hand, but I believe these parameters were supported there for a while.

Comment: Since `--since` accepts other date formats as well, you can also utilise `date` here, e.g.: `git shortlog --since=$(date -v-1d +%F)`. The `+%F` formats `date` output into a git-parsable string, and the `-v` flag adjusts a date the `date` will display. Check out `-v` usage examples in `man date` for more :).

Comment: Especially useful is relative date.
E.g. if you just finished a sprint of 2 weeks:                                                           
```git shortlog -sn --since="2 weeks"```

Comment: Just wondering why isn't this documented in git-shortlog man page, nor git shortlog -h...

Answer (score 2):

You can get total number of commits through a time period with two different ways:

### First way

Get the total commit by using [second - hour - day - week - month - year]

> Get the total commits by second

```bash
git shortlog -se --count  --since=600.second
```

> Get the total commits by minute

```bash
git shortlog -se --count  --since=30.minute
```

> Get the total commits by day

```bash
git shortlog -se --count  --since=28.day
```

> Get the total commits by week

```bash
git shortlog -se --count  --since=1.week
```

> Get the total commits by month

```bash
git shortlog -se --count  --since=1.month
```

> Get the total commits by year

```bash
git shortlog -se --count --since=2.year
```

### Second way

Using since and before - since take the start date and before take the end date that you want to get commit from it.

```bash
git shortlog -se --count --since="Dec 1 2021"  --before="Jan 3 2022"
```